# Apache Ignite throughput, value size, and max cache count?

Tags: ignite

I'm contemplating using Apache Ignite to build a service that caches hundreds of thousands of audio streams per minute at peek traffic.  I was planning to create a new "cache" for every new audio stream.  My question is:

1) Can Ignite handle hundreds of thousands of cache create/deletes over the course of a minute?

2) Can I safely store audio chunks as key value pairs in a cache, or is that kind of throughput and size not recommended?  The audio would be 10-100kb per cache.  We'd probable reach around 20GB/Minute at times.

3) It looks like I can stream to Ignite and do a continuous query to stream from Ignite.  Is my use case valid for these features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is Yes to all 3 questions.

Comment: I just noticed that in capacity planning they say 20MB per cache.  If we have 200,000+ caches, that's 4TB of memory minimum not counting the actual data.  I saw you can reduce this with a setting, but I don't know exactly what IGNITE_ATOMIC_CACHE_DELETE_HISTORY_SIZE means.  Can you explain the impact decreasing that number?

Comment: @user1019182 why do you need 200,000+ caches? You should rethink your data model at this point.

Comment: @user1019182 If all your caches are part of the same cache group, then you will only have 20MB overhead per group. More on cache groups here: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-groups

Comment: @user1019182 I agree with another comment that 200,000 caches is too many. You should think about Ignite caches are RDBMS tables - would you have 200,000 tables in your database?

Comment: Oh I see!  So if I make all 200,000 caches part of the same group, it shouldn't be a problem then.  We're going to have 200,000 cache's created (and expiring) every minute.  The cache's will be holding audio from hundreds of thousands of devices storing audio at random.